# Marshalling LocalDate using XmlJavaTypeAdapter (JAXB) returns null

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, unmarshalling, localdate

I know this question has been asked few times, but even if I use suggested solutions I am unable to get it to work.

What I need is to consume LocalDate coming in as a part of json object. In the following format:

```
 "date":{"year":2016,"month":10,"day":9}
```

As suggested I am using my own XmlAdapter

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {
@Override
public LocalDate unmarshal(String s) throws Exception {
    return LocalDate.parse(s);
}
@Override
public String marshal(LocalDate localDate) throws Exception {
    return localDate.toString();
}
}
```

And I am using annotation in my model class.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDate.class, value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
protected LocalDate date;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDate.class, value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

When debugging, debugger hits the unmarshal method but the string parameter is empty "".

I am using jersey-media-moxy, here's part of my pom

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Would you be so kind as to advise me what am I doing wrong? Thank you :)